# Reloading Asset Between Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

Rails app deployed onto Heroku Cedar stack.

I would like to reload an asset into the pipeline at a given point during runtime.

I'm familiar with `config.cache_classes = false`. Though, in production, the asset is not reloaded after the asset is modified. Any ideas as to the cause of this anomaly?

Answer (score 0):

check with following things.

Make sure that your production.rb settings include:

1 - Your production configuration may not be correct.
     This is particularly likely if you started out with an early 3.1 release candidate, 
     and have been updating along the way. The suggested options for production.rb 
     changed  quite a bit between rc4 and the 3.1.0 release.

```
  #Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  #Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false
  #Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

2 - You may have forgotten to precompile your assets
       RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
3 - You may have forgotten to restart your web server to pick up the changes in production.rb